# Uncaught error :Cannot find the class inside a directory

Tags: php, namespaces

Why do I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Inc\Hello' not found in
>   THE_PATH/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php

This is the structure

```
my-plugin.php
-- Inc
   Hello.php
```

This is the simplified content of my-plugin.php

```
<?php 
 if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php')){
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
 }
Inc\Hello::register_services();
```

And the Hello.php

```
<?php 
namespace Inc;
class Hello{
    function __construct(){}
    public static register_services(){

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use an autoloader so PHP knows how to load your files

Comment: `Hello.php` is not included in `my-plugin.php`

Comment: Thanks guys. I realized that I either have to include the file as Karlo said or update autoloader as JimL suggested. It's working find now.